# "Failed to find a kernelspec to use for ipykernel launch" error happens when I run on virtual studio

Tags: python

Hi I am using virtual studio and running the command on Jupiter notebook.
But this error happens.

"Failed to find a kernelspec to use for ipykernel launch"

Why can't I execute the command this time?

Comment: What command do you try? What did you do? Please elaborate a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation. I was trying to switch from Anaconda to VS Code to run jupyter notebooks. Installed the extension for jupyter notebook and every time I tried creating an empty notebook and basic commands failed to run. On the top right corner, I noticed that the kernel just showed Busy. If you click on that it would ask for a kernel.

I was able to get it working after I installed the python extension on vscode.. not sure if this is the best approach though!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Python libraries Jupyter and ipykernel. On my VS Code editor, a prompt came up saying that ipykernel is missing, and clicking the "install" button would solve it.